# How to use chart.addseries inside for loop in highcharts

Tags: loops

I am using the following code:

```
var chart = $('#soil-chart').highcharts();
                                              chart.addSeries({
                                                  data: test_0
                                              });
                                              chart.addSeries({
                                                  data: test_1
                                              });
                                              chart.addSeries({
                                                  data: test_2
                                              });
```

It is working fine. I was just wondering is it possible to use one chart.addSeries inside a for loop. For example:

```
 for(var i = 0; i <mydefinedArray.length; i++)
    {
     chart.addSeries({
                  data: test_i
                    });
    }
```

I was trying to do that. It is not working actually. Is there any way to do that. Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

It works, but you use the same variable, so series "overlap" next serie. (http://jsfiddle.net/8x9P3/)

See example which works well.
http://jsfiddle.net/8x9P3/1/

```
 for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        var data = [Math.random(0,100)*100,Math.random(0,100)*10];
        chart.addSeries({
                data: data
        });
    }
```

Comment: How I am using same variable? I am using test_i as an my array.

Comment: "i" variable is not parsed in your way as "test1", "test2", I advice to familiar with the javascript tutorials, how to combine it.